# Throw when reassigning

Tags: c++, exception-safety

```
try
{
    object = mayThrow();
}
catch (const std::exception& exc)
{
    //...
}
```

If `mayThrow()` actually throws, will the original `object` be untouched? Or is it better to do it this way?

```
try
{
    Object newObject = mayThrow();
    object = std::move(newObject);
}
catch (const std::exception& exc)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, `object` does not change its state. If it's not global and not accessed in `mayThrow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `mayThrow()` has direct access to `object` and does some monkeying within, the final assignment happens if and only if `mayThrow()` returns successfully and the object stays unchanged otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

> If mayThrow() actually throws, will the original object be untouched?

Yes, `object` is unchanged if/when `mYThrow` throws(assuming `myThrow` has no connection internally with `object` and do not affect `object` in any way).

For example, say `object` is of some **class-type** then the body of the copy assignment operator will be entered only when `myThrow` succeeds. In other words, in this case `object` will be left unchanged.